# spring shell method parameter List<>

Tags: method-parameters, spring-shell

How can I have a spring shell method with a List<> parameter?
is it possible to use List<> as method parameter in Spring_Shell?

as below:

```
     public void test(
        @CliOption(key = "name", help ="") final String name,
        @CliOption(key = "activities",help ="") final List<String> activitiy){//....... something to do}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do that, but it will be up to you to provide the [Converter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/21a993d6bfd410395bdcbf0dad417ef874977985/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/core/Converter.java) for it. It would be much better to use a `String[]` (and optionally convert it to a `List<String>` as your first instruction in your method body if you really need to), as arrays are [supported out of the box](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/21a993d6bfd410395bdcbf0dad417ef874977985/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/converters/ArrayConverter.java) (and support conversion and completion, which is impossible with `List`, because of type erasure)